# bypassing gadget.openPrintDialog()

Tags: javascript, android

is there a way to bypass gadget.openPrintDialog()?
i want to print a receipt without having a dialogue.

I am currently using the following function:

```
out.println(" <script>");
out.println("  var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();");
out.println("gadget.setPrintDocument(\"text/html\", \"Print\", document.documentElement.innerHTML);");
out.println("gadget.openPrintDialog();");
out.println(" </script>");
```

Thanks!